# Solr Exact Query

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am using SolrNet to try and perform an exact query search

I have a document with the URL stored in Solr as : file://C:/Users/me/docs/X%20Item3

I want to match all documents that contain "X Item", so will be looking for a *"X Item"*

I have

```
new SolrQueryByField("url", "*\"X Item\"*");
```

But this does not return the document.  I also do not want to have to convert space characters to %20 but I may have to if Solr will not do it for when it parses the query.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Solr does not support wildcard searches by default at the beginning of a term. You can work around this by adding a `ReversedWildcardFilter` to the field indexing definition.

Depending on the kind of searches performed, you could also split on / to index each part of the path separately, or just the file name.

You shouldn't have to convert spaces to %20, as that should be performed by the client library (I'm not familiar with how SolrNet does it, but it really should abstract that away from you) when making an HTTP request.

Comment: where is the wildcard queries starting with the wildcard character not working by default documented?

Comment: Last note: [Query Parser Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches). It's also a natural limitation of how most indexes work.

Comment: the thing is that http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=* returns the same number of documents as http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=*:* for me, and looking at the code for `WildcardQuery` in lucene i do not see that note enforced

Comment: @omu_negru I'd like to point out that a single * is not the same as *<strings> and can be shortcut, but yes, the current documentation is torn: it says it isn't supported, as well as instead saying "should not start with ..". Seems it should work now. (btw: the decision to use a wildcard expansion is the parser, which now checks if there's a reverse version available afaict)

Comment: * is a wildcard query that will match anything, so if you really want to optimize it in your query parser, you could just return a *:* match all docs query, but not all query parsers will do that